# Mongo Projection filter with subarray

Tags: mongodb, projection

```
{
"_id" : "000f7ef7-b4d2-4b3a-a33a-ce4f5a6dc594",
"ClientCode" : "67018",
"ClientName" : "test06",    
"Addresses" : [ 
    {            
        "AddressTypeCode" : "1",             
        "EmailAddress" : "test1@gmail.com"
    }, 
    {            
        "AddressTypeCode" : "2",                         
        "EmailAddress" : "test2@gmail.com"
    }
    , 
    {            
        "AddressTypeCode" : "3",            
        "EmailAddress" : "test3@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

}

I would like to get the followings results using mongo projection with filter condition for the subarray Address with AddressTypeCode equals 1 and get the email address.

```
{  "ClientCode" : "67018",  "ClientName" : "test06",  "EmailAddress" :test1@gmail.com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first do an unwind:

```
{ $unwind : "$Addresses" }
```

Then do a match:

```
{ $match : { "Addresses.AddressTypeCode" : "1" } }
```

Then do the projection:

```
{ $project : { "ClientCode" : 1, "ClientName" : 1, "EmailAddress" : "$Addresses.AddressTypeCode" } }
```